# AutoIt 3 Inputing keyboard keys by GUI

Tags: user-interface, autoit

How can I create a GUI element like the one of type "Input" that would register current keyboard keystroke, but I'm not talking about any letter or number, but rather special buttons like CTRL, TAB or Enter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know there is no special GUI element handling that.
There are some "workarounds" like

1. When something gets written check if CTRL (or anything else) is pressed

   _IsPressed()
2. Catch if you press CTRL with Hotkey and then make a Funktion to insert it into the Input

   HotKeySet({CTRL},_insertCTRL);

Does one of these work for you?

Comment: I love the 2nd method, I'm not sure if it will prove viable in this current project as it will have multiple inputs but I will surely use it in future, thanks!

Comment: Glad that i could help :)